# Graylog2 mongo profiler plugin won't connect to mongo instance, error: "Exception opening socket" (everything dockerized)

Tags: mongodb, graylog2

I am trying to play with graylog's mongo profiler plugin using docker to run everything. But I can't get any profiling logs into graylog.

When I start the mongo input from the graylog UI it eventually times out with an error:

> Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:37017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}].

---

This is my setup based on following the [graylog dockerhub installation](https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog2/server/) and the [mongo profiler plugin guide](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-plugin-mongodb-profiler) and modifying bits:

(1) I bring up graylog, mongo and elastic using a docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  some-mongo:
    image: "mongo:3"
  some-elasticsearch:
    image: "elasticsearch:2"
    command: "elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name='graylog'"
  graylog:
    image: graylog2/server:2.2.1-1
    environment:
      GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET: somepasswordpepper
      GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2: 8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
      GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI: http://127.0.0.1:9000/api
    links:
      - some-mongo:mongo
      - some-elasticsearch:elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "514:514/udp"
      - "12202:12202"
      - "37017:37017"
```

That has worked fine so far and I've been able to send in syslog udp messages and gelf http messages.

(2) I created a separate mongo docker container with ports mapped because I worry that if I use 27017, that graylog might look in its own internal mongodb container:

```
docker run -d -p 37017:27017 mongo:2.4
```

I start a mongo session and enable profiling for a "graylog" database:

```
$ mongo --port 37017
> use graylog
> db.setProfilingLevel(2)
{ "was" : 0, "slowms" : 100, "ok" : 1 }
> db.foo.insert({_id:1})

// Check that profiling data is being written to system.profile:
> db.system.profile.find().limit(1).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty()
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "graylog.foo",
    "query" : {

    },
    "ntoreturn" : 0,
    "ntoskip" : 0,
    ....
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

So it seems like the mongod instance is running and profiling is working.

(3) I download the plugin jar and `docker cp` it into the plugins dir inside the graylog docker container. Something like:

```
docker cp graylog-plugin-mongodb-profiler-2.0.1.jar e89a2decda37:/usr/share/graylog/plugin
```

Then restart graylog.

I can see that the file is there:

```
$ docker exec -it e89a2decda37 /bin/sh
# ls /usr/share/graylog/plugin
graylog-plugin-anonymous-usage-statistics-2.2.1.jar  graylog-plugin-map-widget-2.2.1.jar
graylog-plugin-beats-2.2.1.jar               graylog-plugin-mongodb-profiler-2.0.1.jar
graylog-plugin-collector-2.2.1.jar           graylog-plugin-pipeline-processor-2.2.1.jar
graylog-plugin-enterprise-integration-2.2.1.jar
```

So that part seemed to work fine and I can see an entry "Mongo profiler input" in the list of input types in the graylog UI.

(4) I create a "Mongo profiler input" input with:

- hostname: localhost
- port: 37017
- database: graylog

(5) After I click save, the input tries to start then eventually fails like above. Restarting graylog or trying to restart the input results in the same failures.

---

I have tried step (2) with different versions of mongo in case there was some driver incompatibility but they all fail with same error. I've tried docker images:

- mongo:3
- mongo:2.6
- mongo:2.4

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a) do you still need the "some-mongo" that runs together with Graylog?  b) It seems Graylog tries to connect to the external Mongo using "localhost". Not sure if this can work, as "localhost" would refer to its own container. Try using the IP address of the Docker host.

Comment: @Thilo a) that's the mongo instance for graylog itself. It stores some metadata inside that. b) Yes this worked! Danke Thilo! :cookie:

Answer (score 1):

Like Thilo suggested [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391956/graylog2-mongo-profiler-plugin-wont-connect-to-mongo-instance-error-exceptio#comment71964539_42391956), the hostname for the graylog input shouldn't be "localhost" as that will point graylog to the docker container hosting it.

So I found the ip of the host machine using:

```
docker exec -it [CONTAINER ID] /bin/sh
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

and rewired the input and Bob's your Uncle!